# Let $R \subseteq S$ be two local PIDs with the same field of fractions, then $R=S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ and $S$ be two local principal ideal domains with the same field of fractions $K$. I want to show that if $R\subseteq S$ then $R=S$.

I will denote as $\mathfrak{m}_R=(m_R)$ and $\mathfrak{m}_S=(m_S)$ the unique maximal ideal of the local rings $R$ and $S$ respectively. Then every non-unit of $R$ is of the form $x=m_R^nu$  for some $n\in\mathbb{N} $ and some unit $u\in R$. Same goes for $S$. I though of using the following Lemma to attack this problem.

$\textbf{Lemma}$ $\colon$ *Let $R$ be a local PID with field of fractions $K$. Let $S$ be any local domain with $R\subseteq S\subseteq K$. If $\mathfrak{m}_R \subseteq \mathfrak{m}_S$, then $R=S$*

I know that for local $R$ it is true that its maximal ideal consists of all the non-units. Also, if $R$ is a PID then, $x\in K$ implies that $x\in R$ or $x^{-1} \in R$ (or both). Let $x\in \mathfrak{m}_R$, thus $x^{-1} \notin R$. Now $x^{-1}$ cannot  be in $\mathfrak{m}_S$ because then, since $x\in \mathfrak{m}_R\Rightarrow x \in R \Rightarrow x\in S$ we would have that $1=xx^{-1} \in \mathfrak{m}_S$ which is a contradiction. How can i prove that in fact $x^{-1}$ can't be in $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $S=T^{-1}R$ where $T$ is a multiplicative subset of $R$. This is true whenever $R$ is a PID. Now use the fact that R is local PID to show that $T^{-1}R = R $ or $K$

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was enlightening. The intuition i thought of is that if an element $x\in \mathfrak{m}_R$ ie $x=m_R^nu$ is a unit in $S$ then, $m_R$ is invertible in $S$ and hence, every element of $R$ is invertible in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true: Take $S = K$ the field of fractions of $R$.

This is the only counter-example: if $R \subseteq S \subseteq K$ and $S$ contains an element of the form $u m_{R}^{n}$ with $u \in R^{\times}$ and $n < 0$, it follows that $S = K$. Thus either $S = R$ or $S = K$.

Comment: The exercise as i wrote it, is Exercise 2.4 in Lorenzini's book _An invitation in Arithmetic Geometry_  I see why you say it is not true. Can it be true if we assume that $R\subseteq S \subsetneq K$

Comment: I can't see why an element of the form $um_R^n$ with $u \in R^{\times}$ and $n>0$ is in $S$ implies that $S=K$. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Every element of $K$ is of the form $u m_R^n$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$. If $m_R^{n_0} \in S$ with $n_0 < 0$, then for each $n < 0$, $um_R^{n} = um_R^{n-N n_0} \cdot (m_R^{n_0})^{N} \in R \cdot S = S$, by choosing $N$ large enough so that $n-Nn_0 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt.

R and S be defined as given in the statement. Let $\displaystyle M_{R}$ and $\displaystyle M_{S}$ be the unique maximal ideals of R and S respectively.

Claim: $\displaystyle M_{R} \subseteq M_{S}$

Let $\displaystyle x\in M_{R}$ then this implies that $\displaystyle x$ is a non unit and $\displaystyle x\in R\subseteq S$. And hence $\displaystyle x\in S$ and it is also a non unit in S. Since $\displaystyle M_{S}$ is maximal ideal of non units in S, hence $\displaystyle x\in M_{S}$. Claim is proved . Now by the Lemma given in the question we conclude that $\displaystyle R=S$.